# Python remove inner brackets and keep outer brackets

Tags: python, regex, string-parsing

I am struggling with Regex, I have read the wiki and played around, but I cant seem to make the right match.

```
string_before = 'President [Trump] first name is [Donald], so his full name is [[Donald] [Trump]]' 
string_after = 'President [Trump] first name is [Donald], so his full name is [Donald Trump]'
```

I want to remove any possible brackets inside the outer brackets while keeping the outer brackets and the text inside.

Could this be solved easy in python without regex?

Comment: Regex is not that good for dealing with nesting.

Comment: Where are you getting text with these brackets to begin with?

Comment: I have done named entity tagging. And names are tagged with [ ] around them. So in this case, the tagger belives we have 3 diffrent entities since Donald is a entity, Trump is a entity and Donald Trump is another entity. This is a special case when, 'Donald' might been mentioned in the beginning of the text and 'Trump' in the middle and then the new combination 'Donald Trump' in the end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the specific case of two adjacent bracketed expressions inside a pair of brackets, you can do

```
string = re.sub(r'\[\[([^][]+)\] \[([^][]+)\]\]', r'[\1 \2]', string)
```

This does not conveniently extend to an arbitrary number of adjacent bracketed expressions, but perhaps it's enough for your needs.

Answer (score 1):

Regex will cause you more harm than good for such problems. You will need to write some parsing logic based on grammar or rules.

You could for example take a look at Finite-State Transducers ([1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite-state_transducer), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4872202/754581)), which would be a suitable method of parsing nested constructions, but it's more complex than Regex to understand and use.

Answer (score 0):

```
In [1]: import re
In [2]: before='blablabla [[Donald] [Trump]] blablabla'
In [3]: l=before.find('[')+1
In [4]: r=before.rfind(']')
In [5]: before[:l] + re.sub( r'[][]','',before[l:r]) + before[r:]
Out[5]: 'blablabla [Donald Trump] blablabla'
```

Just show one way to go, error checking/handling was omitted.

Comment: Cool, yeah it solves that specific case. I did not ellaborate my examples enough. Since they can look like: "I think [Donald] is the first name of the president [Trump] but some people call him [[Donald] [Trump]] so he shall be called [[Donald] [Trump]]" I will update my question.